# What's the C++ GUI building option with the easiest learning curve - VS/Qt/wxWidgets/etc.?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, user-interface, qt, wxwidgets

I'm looking to be able to build GUI applications quickly and painlessly as possible. I'm competent (though not expert, and have no formal training) in C++, but have never used a GUI building toolkit or framework or anything. I am not a professional programmer and am totally inexperienced and ignorant when it comes to building GUI apps. Have spent hours researching trying to figure out what to do; only getting more confused and discouraged though.

Qt and wxWidgets seem like the most popular options for cross-platform apps, though cross-platform isn't necessarily all that important to me; Windows-only is fine if that means the fastest learning curve.

Qt seems cool and the Qt Creator is sweet looking with lots of good demos, except it has its own classes for everything, and I'm not overly keen on learning a bunch of stuff that's only applicable to the Qt platform itself rather than more generally. I suppose I could avoid using the Qt classes except for the GUI stuff where I have to use them, but I have no idea how wise or unwise that would be.

I was thinking Visual Studio would have the smallest learning curve, but when I open a test GUI app, I see a bunch of foreign looking stuff like carats (^) all over the place - I found online that these mean "handles", which I have trouble even understanding the definition or purpose of ("sort of like pointers but not really" is basically how I've read people define them).

I know pretty much nothing about wxWidgets, or how it compares with Qt.

So every option has a big learning curve - and ideally I'd like to know which one minimizes the time you have to spend learning the toolkit/framework itself. Since I'm likely never going to be making money from the programs I create, the time I spend learning a specific toolkit would be pretty costly. I just want to be able to make a functional program using the C++ knowledge I have, but in GUI form. At the moment it seems if I want to make a GUI app, I'd have to spend way more time learning the GUI framework I'd use than writing the functional part of the app itself.

Any input from people wiser and more experienced than me would be appreciated :)

Comment: All those carats in VC++ are for C++/CLI. They are .NET specific additions to the language that allow for integration with the CLR.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First and foremost, start simple.  There's a lot to the subject.  If you are finding it hard, don't try and take it in all at once.

Most of the good GUI packages have tutorials.  The best advice I can give is that you try each of them, or at least a couple of them.  They are the best short introduction you can have to the library you choose and if they are any good they narrow down what you need to absorb at first.  That will give you some basis for comparison, because they are each trying to do very similar things (and you will see some of them before you are done), but they have different feels.  You will likely find you have a preference for one and that's the one to get serious with.  It will also give you a sense of what's hard about GUI programming as *separate* from the particulars of one package, which, if you have only used one, you won't have seen.  Personally I find this sort of knowledge very helpful, because it makes me less intimidated by particulars.

Here's a list of tutorials in one place, though you have likely seen them already:

- [Qt's tutorial](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtexamplesandtutorials.html)
- [WxWidgets' tutorial](http://www.wxwidgets.org/docs/tutorials.htm)
- [Gtkmm book](http://www.gtkmm.org/docs/gtkmm-2.4/docs/tutorial/html/index.html).  Not *quite* a tutorial, though there are lots of examples.
- .NET tutorials, either for WinForms or for WPF.

Second, it sounds to me that you need to get some in depth understanding of the *concepts* of GUI programming, not just a particular library.  Here there is no substitute for a book. I don't know all of them by a long shot, but the best of the bunch will not just teach you the details of a toolkit, they will teach you general concepts and how to use them.  Here are some lists to start with though (and once you have titles, Amazon and Stack Overflow will help to pick one):

- [List of Qt books](http://www.qtsoftware.com/developer/books)
- [WxWidgets book](http://www.wxwidgets.org/docs/book/) ([PDF version](http://www.informit.com/content/images/0131473816/downloads/0131473816_book.pdf))
- There are tons of WPF and WinForms books.  I can't make a good recommendation here unfortunately.

Third, take advantage of the design tools (Qt Creator, VS's form building and so on).  *Don't* start by trying to read through all the code they generate: get your own small programs running first.  Otherwise it's too hard to know what matters for a basic program and what doesn't.  The details get lost.  Once you've got the basics down though, *Do* use them as references to learn how to do specific effects.  If you can get something to work in the design tools, then you can look at *particular* code they generate to be able to try on your own hand-written programs.  They are very useful for intermediate learning.

> I'm not overly keen on learning a bunch of stuff that's only applicable to the Qt platform itself rather than more generally.

I second the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1189084/whats-the-c-gui-building-option-with-the-easiest-learning-curve-vs-qt-wxwidg/1189334#1189334) of GRB here: Don't worry about this.  You are going to need to learn a lot specific to the toolkit no matter which toolkit you use.  But you will also learn a lot that's *general* to GUI programming with any of the decent toolkits, because they are going to have to cover a lot of the same ground.  Layouts, events, interaction between widgets/controls, understanding timers -- these will come up in any GUI toolkit you use.

However do be aware that any serious GUI package *is* an investment of time.  You will have a much easier time learning a second package if you decide to pick one up, but every large library has its personality and much of your time will be spent learning its quirks.  That is, I think, a given in dealing with any complex subject.

> I suppose I could avoid using the Qt classes except for the GUI stuff where I have to use them, but I have no idea how wise or unwise that would be.

You do not need most of the non-GUI classes of Qt to use Qt's GUI properly.  There are a handful of exceptions (like `QVariant`) which you'll need just because the GUI classes use them.  I found you can learn those on a case-by-case basis.

Answer (score 12):

Which is the easiest to learn is really going to depend on how you personally learn.

*Personally*, I've found Qt to be the easiest to learn so far. The GUI classes are rather nice to use, but I've found the non-GUI classes to be excellent, making it easy to avoid a lot of common issues you'd normally get with a more basic API. The [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/) is excellent, IMO, as are the books, the examples, etc. It's also being very actively developed, with a few new technologies coming in the near future (like DeclarativeUI).

I've found Visual Studio/Windows API/.Net to be a good bit more complicated to learn. The API documentation on MSDN is rather complicated and not really organized in a manner that I find intuitive.

I've tried learning WxWidgets a few times, but I've never liked the API documentation.

All this is just my personal experience, YMMV of course. I'd say just dabble in all of them and see which one takes you the furthest, it won't hurt to try multiple.

Comment: I second this recommendation.  I used Qt so my app would be cross-platform.  Usually committing to cross-platform results in MORE work, but because Qt was so well laid out and helpful in general, I found it to be actually more productive than writing a single-OS target app in, for example, C# - especially if you get stuck in the quasi-C++ world of managed code (those carats).  That said, I agree with the other comments here to pace yourself, there's a lot to learn.  But there's a lot of reward if you hang in there - nothing more rewarding than seeing your efforts on screen.  :-)

Answer (score 8):

As a person who learned C++ through Qt, I can only say that they work very well together. C++ purists (like I have become) will find lots of things in Qt not to their liking (the `moc` preprocessor, e.g., and the continued absence of exceptions for error reporting), but looking back, Qt provided a *very* gentle introduction to C++ for me.

And if you're like me, you throw in a handful of boost libs in each Qt project, because we want to write "real" C++, not the softened thing Qt uses :)

Answer (score 7):

I would suggest wxWidgets. To me, it's pretty intuitive and looks nice.

[Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/) was built with it, so check that out to see if you like the graphics.

There are also a slew of bindings for wxWidgets, such as wxPython, wxErlang, and others, so if you decide to switch off of C++, you can take wxWidgets with you.

Answer (score 5):

I also use wxWidgets and use it all the time for Windows-only applications (the only downside is that wxWidgets is notorious for large .exe filesizes, which may or may not be a problem for you). I found it very simple to use from the start, especially when combined with a GUI designer (personally I use wxDev-C++).

I've never used Qt, so I can't speak to its simplicity, but I doubt the difficulty is on a vastly different scale than that of wxWidgets. However, what I can say is that no matter what API you use (wxWidgets, Qt, WinAPI, etc) your code will be "locked into" that particular platform, so don't worry if you feel that learning Qt will lock you into the Qt platform (because the same thing will happen with *any* of those APIs).

If you're working solely on Windows however, you may want to do a few simple programs with WinAPI first. That way you have a basic understanding of the lowest level of Windows GUI programming before you move onto Qt/wxWidgets. That said, if you're really into cross-platform programming, then don't worry about that and go straight into Qt/wxWidgets.

Answer (score 2):

I can't intelligently comment on the learning curve aspect, but a quick survey of StackOverflow questions shows about twice as many Visual C++ questions as Qt questions.  Probably means that there is a larger support group in place for Visual C++.  Might make learning it a little easier if there are more folks to help out.

Comment: Or it means that VC++ is twice as confusing as Qt.  :-)  Or that there's lots of VC++ questions that don't relate to graphics.  I believe the community here can support both well.

Answer (score 2):

No matter what you pick, I am quite sure it won't be easy and painless.

Having said that, I know that in some schools they use [FLTK](http://www.fltk.org/) because they consider it relativelly easy to learn. I have never tried it.

In my everyday work I use WTL which is as close to the system as it gets while still providing some level of abstraction over pure Win32. I am not sure if I would consider it easy to learn, though, especially given the lack of documentation.

Comment: FLTK is fairly easy to work with and is fairly cross-platform.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend codegear C++ builder (previously known as borland C++ builder) from [codegear](http://www.codegear.com) which comes with a 30 trial. The nicest thing about it is that the GUI provides you with components that you drop onto a form in a WYSIWYG fashion and make functional by adding code to handle the events it fires. It comes with a whole bunch of compontents out of the box and you can add 3rd party components to it too, like the awesome ExpressQuantumGrid from [devexpress](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/VCL/ExQuantumGrid/), or write your own. It's very powerfull if you know what you're doing but  intuitive enough that a beginner can write a database CRUD application in about 20 lines of very simple code.

Answer (score 1):

Since nobody has mentioned it yet, for the sake of completeness, have a plug for [the Fox toolkit](http://www.fox-toolkit.org/).  This is the one I used last time I did any C++ UI work of my own volition.  There are also binding for this to Ruby and Python (the latter being many years out of date, though).

In general, the choice of a toolkit for self-directed work comes down to personal preferences for

1. the layout manager style
2. the event handler registration style
3. How native the widget set looks/can be made to look

Answer (score 1):

If cross-platforming is not necessary, try `.net` + `msvs` or `delphi`. easy, all-in-one, no pain.

Answer (score 0):

Qt is the best option for you. It's the easiest to learn, the most elegant and powerful and it is completely free.

- Visual C++: This is an IDE, but it comes with its own GUI library called MFC. MFC is an old library with many quirks and it is difficult to learn and use. Many C++ programmers use it on Windows because it comes from MS, it's fast and it's free if you buy Visual C++. Since VC++ is an IDE, you can also use wxWidgets and Qt with it, although in your particular case I would recommend Qt Creator instead.

You seem to have experimented with Managed C++. Don't use that, even MS recommends that you only use Managed C++ as glue between C++ and C#.

- wxWidgets: This one was a strong contender up to the day when Qt became free for commercial projects. It was always in the shadow of Qt and it is known that the documentation is not very good and the API is not as easy to learn as Qt's. Cross-platform MFC would be a good way to describe it.
- C++ Builder: Borland made too many mistakes with C++ Builder and ended up getting out of the dev tools business altogether. It was a good product and I originally learned Windows GUI programming in one of the first versions, but I won't use it any more. There are better options and it is too expensive.